# How to set Discord.js v13 slash commands permissions?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm following the Discord.js guide to create slash commands for my bot, but I'm stuck at this point here:
https://discordjs.guide/interactions/slash-command-permissions.html#user-permissions

There are **two things I can't figure out**:

- where I'm supposed to write this block of code I linked above,
- how I'm supposed to find each command's ID

I'm creating my commands using the `SlashCommandBuilder` and a `deploy-commands.js` script as described here:
https://discordjs.guide/creating-your-bot/creating-commands.html#command-deployment-script
and here:
https://discordjs.guide/interactions/registering-slash-commands.html#guild-commands

If you can help me on either one of these two things, that would be great!
Thanks!

Comment: Could you may provide your current code? (at least some of it?)

Comment: Of course, here: https://github.com/OIIOIIOI/rd72-bot

Comment: Ill guess your repository is private, so i dont have access to it. If you want you can click on my profile, go to my github profile and add me to the repository. Than i will take a look

Comment: My bad, I changed it to public

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've looked into the codes of the `@discordjs/builders` and `@discordjs/rest` and there is no way to set custom permissions with these packages. What you can do is create the slash commands with the `Discord.js` package. By creating them in the `Discord.js` package the id of the slash command will be returned in the fullfilled `Promise`. With this id you can set the permissions for the command. The only problem by doing it in this way is that it can take a while before the slash commands are working again. Here is an example:

```js
const { Client } = require('discord.js');

const client = new Client({intents: ['Your Intents here']});

client.once('ready', () => {
   client.application.commands.create({
      name: 'your_command',
      description: "Your command's description"
   }).then(id => {
      client.application.commands.set({command: id, permissions: [
           id: 'some_user_id',
           type: 'USER',
           permission: false // Can not use the slash command
      ]}).catch(console.log);
   });
});

client.login('Your token here');
```

I thought that there is another way to do it, but I'm not pretty sure. If I'm right you can also fetch all the commands after you've refreshed them with the `@discordjs/builders` and `@discordjs/rest` packages. Once you've fetched them the `Promise` will return a `Collection` once it's got fullfilled. In the `Collection` will be all the ids of all the slash commands which you can use to set the permissions. So if this theory works, this will be the example:

```js
const { Client } = require('discord.js');

const client = new Client({intents: ['Your Intents here']});

client.once('ready', () => {
    // Your refresh code here
    client.application.commands.fetch().then(collection => {
        collection.forEach(command => {
            if(command.name === `The specified command name`){
                 client.application.commands.permissions.set({command: command.id, permissions: [
                     {
                         id: 'some_user_id',
                         type: 'USER',
                         permission: false // Can not use the slash command
                     }
                 ]}).catch(console.log);
            }
        });
    }).catch(console.log);
});

client.login('Your token here');
```

Comment: Doing the forEach loop in the ready event is indeed working!  
I've updated the repo accordingly.  

Thanks!